# Store image in Firebase Storage from within a Firebase Database function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an app in Firebase and I'm trying to insert an image in Firebase Storage from within a Real-time Database function.

The function is triggered when a record is inserted in the DB.

The record contains an image URL.

What I understand is that I need to read this image to get a base64 string and store this string as an image in Firebase Storage but I have no idea how to achieve that.

It seems that I can't have access to the Firebase storage object inside the function, I can only access the Bucket via `admin.storage().bucket()` and I can't find any function (like put() in the storage object) allowing me to put a base64 string as an image inside Firebase storage.

So far I tried to store the image that way with no success :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: 'gs://my-bucket.appspot.com',
});

exports.handler = (event) => {
  const myBase64Image = 'someImageInBase64';
  admin.storage().bucket('folder').file('test').save(myBase64Image);
};
```

Do you have any idea how I should do that ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: In a Cloud Function you usually use the Admin SDK. Have a look here for the doc for Storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start?authuser=0. You will find the full API reference here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/?authuser=0. See also this post if you need to fetch the image from the CF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061496/ipfs-module-not-working-with-firebase-functions

Comment: The need for a base64 string isn't really accurate. Take a look at the [Cloud Storage Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

Comment: You can store the image in Cloud Storage. No need to use base64. Check out [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js) example to see how to upload an image

Comment: @Jay, I can't use this guide since the storage object I get in a firebase realtime-database function is not the one described in this guide.

Comment: Not sure I understand that. Firebase Realtime Database doesn't present any storage objects. The Storage API will present a URL to the file (video, audio, image etc) when the item is stored that you would store in Realtime Database so it can be accessed later. In other words, the RTDB doesn't have storage objects - it has Strings, Numbers, Arrays and Dates. That's it.

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to store a file that I fetch from an external URL in the storage.
With your help, so far I've been able to save a local file in the storage but I've no idea how to store something I fetched with the fetch library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally did it !

This is what my handler looks like in the end :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require('request');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  const record = event.after.val();
  const storage = admin.storage.bucket();
  const file = bucket.file('path_to_image.jpg');

  return request(record.pictureUrl).pipe(file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    }
  }));
};
```

Thank you all for your help !!